# jQuery mouseover mouseout opacity

Tags: jquery, mouseover, opacity, mouseout

```
    function hoverOpacity() {
    $('#fruit').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 1500);
      });
    $('#fruit').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1500);
      });
}
```

This is my function that animates `div#fruit`, and it does it work.

The problem is this; When you `mouseout` before the `mousein` animation finishes, it has to complete the animation before starting the `mouseout`. (hope that makes sense)

This isn't usually noticeable, but with a long duration, it is noticeable.

Instead of finishing the animation, I want the animation to stop and reverse to the original state.

Comment: thanks for the response's everyone.
the stop function led me to the following page which is exactly wat I needed:
http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop) function, possibly followed by `show` (or `hide`, or `css`, depends what state you want `opacity` to end up in).

```
function hoverOpacity() {
    $('#fruit').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 1500);
      });
    $('#fruit').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({opacity: 1}, 1500);
      });
}
```

The `true` tells the animation to jump to the end. If this is the only animation on the element, it should be fine; otherwise, as I said, you could look at `css` to explicitly set the desired opacity.

Separately, though, you might look at using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` rather than `mouseover` and `mouseout`, for two reasons: 1. `mouseover` repeats as the mouse moves across the element, and 2. Both `mouseover` and `mouseout` *bubble*, and so if your "fruit" element has child elements, you'll receive events from them as well, which tends to destabilize this kind of animation.

Comment: @a-second-mix: See also the note about possibly using different events for this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a call to `.stop()` before you animate to clear the current and any queued animations:

```
function hoverOpacity() {
    $('#fruit').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 1500);
      });
    $('#fruit').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({opacity: 1}, 1500);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function hoverOpacity() {
    $('#fruit').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 1500);
      });
    $('#fruit').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 1}, 1500);
      });
}
```

This should stop the animation, clear the queue (first arg) and jump to the end (second arg), you can change / mess around with the arguments as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

try this aswell:

```
function hoverOpacity() {
    $('#fruit').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 1500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1500);
    });
}
```